# How to expand this function?

Tags: power-series

How to expand the complex function $$f(z)=\frac{1}{z^{2}+4}$$ at the region $|z-2i|>4$?  Maybe i can use the standard geometric series with substitude?

Martin Ferrer suggested in comments that I use partial fractions.  My partial fraction decomposition is $$f(z)=\frac{1}{4i}\left(\frac{1}{z-2i}-\frac{1}{z+2i}\right)$$  But now how do I use the fact that I am in the region $|z-2i|>4$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: use $z^2+4=(z+2i)(z-2i)$ and partial fractions. Then you can use geometric series to both fractions.

Comment: @MarcosEscartínFerrer Can you show me your steps,please?

Comment: Yeah, but first I want you to do some work, you know how to do partial fractions? Where do you get stucked? Tell me what you tried and I can complete your answer.

Comment: Yeah, here is my step: $\frac{1}{z^{2}+4}=\frac{1}{4i}(\frac{1}{z-2i}-\frac{1}{z+2i})$ , but since i want to expand the function at a region |z-2i|>4, how should i use the geometric series to achieve that?

Comment: Notice that $\frac{1}{z+2i}=\frac{1}{z+4i-2i}=\frac{\frac{1}{4i}}{\frac{z-2i}{4i}+1}$, can you finish from this?

Comment: @MarcosEscartínFerrer  Ah, i see, thank you very much !!

Comment: Maybe you can try to write a full solution, so If can check if you did it ok. Also It can be useful for more people.

Comment: So after the arrangement, the equation will be f(z)=\frac{1}{4i}[\frac{1}{1-2i}-\frac{1}{z+2i}]

Comment: @MarcosEscartínFerrer But just a quick question, what should I do about the term \frac{1}{z-2i}, how should i expand this term at the region |z-2i|>4????

Comment: You are expanding in powers of $z-2i$ so this is already expanded.

Comment: omg, what was i think. Thank you , now i totally understand it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f(z)=$\frac{1}{z^{2}+4}$=$\frac{1}{4i}(\frac{1}{z-2i}-\frac{1}{z+2i})=\frac{1}{4i}(\frac{1}{z-2i}-\frac{\frac{1}{4i}}{1+\frac{z-2i}{4i}})=\frac{1}{4i}(\frac{1}{z-2i}-\frac{1}{4i}\sum_{n=0}^{n=\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}(4i)^{n}}{(z-2i)^n})$ valid when $|\frac{z-2i}{4i}|>1$ which is $|z-2i|>4$

Comment: This is perfect, well done.